# removing sqs as an event source for lambda in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am looking for a way to remove SQS from lambda as an event source, I know how to do in console but is there a way to do it in Java?

Comment: Any code that you have so far? V1 or V2 of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS SDK for Java. The method is DeleteEventSourceMapping on the LambdaClient class.

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/LambdaClient.html#deleteEventSourceMapping-software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.DeleteEventSourceMappingRequest-